# How to overdesign a shell

Tags: java, shell, oop, design-patterns

Yesterday I stumpled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399298/design-pattern-command-for-switch-java/), it asks about creating a OO shell<sup>*</sup> with use of the [command design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

It made me curious, because I always hated my shells (a cascade of ifs and elses). I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400841/1809463) the question with a fully working example.

Here's a little excerpt that depicts the main idea

```
private final Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            System.out));
    private boolean quit = false;

    private Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();
    {
        commands.put("create", new CreateChat(this));
        commands.put("join", new JoinChat(this));
        commands.put("exit", new ExitCommand(this));
    }

    public void run() throws IOException {
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            writer.write("> ");
            writer.flush();
            while (!quit && s.hasNextLine()) {
                String input = s.nextLine().trim();

                // get or default is java8, alternatively you could check for null
                Command command = commands.getOrDefault(input, new UnknownCommand(this, input));
                command.execute();

                if (!quit)
                    writer.write("> ");
                writer.flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

Still, I'm not completely pleased. I'd prefer a declarative solution, where you can specify the commands and map them to a appropiate instance of the `Command` interface.

My problem herin is, that I'm not sure how to handle complex inputs, e.g.

`collect sample <sequence<double>>`

`collect sample 1.0 1.5 1.33 1.45`

or `class teacher <name> pupils <name> <name> ...`

I could hand the command instances a `Reader` object, but I feel it is not their responsibility to read their own input. They should have a `CommandParameter` object etc.

But I'm not sure how to design it. I once implemented a binary protocol parsing library which enabled the user to define the protocl via xml, that seems like a solution (but a complex one).

Another question is, how do I tell the user when - and where exactly - formatting errors occur, in case the `CommandParameter` can't be created?

---

**TL;DR**

So to finish with a clear question: 
What are the design patterns one can utilize to create a clean shell (in a declarative way), while respecting all the common
clean code rules (separation of concerns, single responsibility principle, etc.).

*<sup>with 'shell' I mean the part of a (java) program, that reads predefined commands from `System.in` and calls respective methods on the model/controller.</sup>

Comment: If you vote to close, please add a comment. This gives me the chance to modify/clarify the question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, there are two school of thoughts when designing a shell:

1. The Unix Philosophy: "text is the universal interface". Most Unix-inspired tools reads text from stdin and outputs text to stdout to interact with each other. This philosophy of text as universal interface came about because the tools are written in heterogeneous languages by a large number of heterogeneous authors which probably never even meet or hear about each other. One tool can be written in C by someone in Netherlands, another written in Python by a team in Australia, another is a Perl script that has been passed around and modified by countless people in different forums, and so on, and they need to interoperate with each other. The Unix shell have powerful tools that transforms streams of texts to feed the output of one program to another (sed, grep, etc). The drawback is that each tools have to implement their own parsing.
2. Object-based shell, most notably PowerShell, but also the REPL of a more traditional programming languages like Python, Ruby, Lisp. In this philosophy, you'll have objects in the shell and the shell tools exchange these objects rather than texts. An object-based shell is generally easier to use, assuming the authors of the tools have designed their tools to be used together (which is usually the case if all the tools are written by a single author or a single unified group of authors). The drawback is that pretty much everything have to be written in a single language or a group of languages that shares a common runtime (e.g. .NET).

In either case though, the design pattern is simple. In Unix shell philosophy, the tools are declaratively declared in the filesystem as programs and the shell would just execute the programs. In object-based shell philosophy, on the other hand, you'll need to dynamically import the class files and you'll need to use introspection so the shell can figure out how to call the tool.

Comment: `The drawback is that each tools have to implement their own parsing.` I was refering to exactly that parsing. How can you design it? I think we had a little misunderstanding on the term 'shell'. But thanks for your interesting answer!

Comment: @mike: for Unix shells, the parsing is left to the tools, and the shell just have tools that can help transforms texts. Text is universal. Within each tool, it's up to the tool how they parser their input text, some do the full through by defining a grammar in Antlr, EBNF, or Lex/Yacc, other's just regex through the data, and many just simply consumes tokens from the input stream. It's the individual tool that decides how best to parse it's own input, the shell doesn't (need to) define our care about parsing, it just need to setup the stream redirections.

Comment: @mike: The only part that the shell parses is the command line arguments (argv array). In most Unix shells this is simply just splitting the command line argument on whitespace with a way to prevent the splitting by enclosing in quotes or escape character. It's then up to the tool to figure out what to do with the array of strings. Command line completion is simply implemented as a words list or script that returns possible completions for the base program.

Comment: Okay, I think we still have a misunderstanding. By `shell` I mean the part of a (java) program that reads from `System.in` and writes to `System.out`. This is a very ugly process - at least in my previous programs - and I'm searching for a nice, reusable, OO and possibly declarative way. Using a grammer and compiler techniques goes in the right direction.

Comment: @mike: if by shell you mean the command line interface to your program, then no, we're not misunderstanding, that's a shell too, although not a shell that wraps the OS functions, but rather a shell that wraps your program functions. The core idea in my answer is that if you take the unix philosophy, your shell should do the minimal thing and leave the parsing to the subtools; while if you take the object shell approach, the input language and parsing will have to be defined by the shell itself. I'd use something like JSON syntax if I have to input complex structured data in an object shell.

Comment: @mike: another possibility I'd explore is not to write your own shell and parsers and stuffs. But instead, just expose a set of functions that can be used from Jython and let your shell users have the full power of a proper scripting language (python) at their disposal. You might want to have a launcher that starts a Jython shell with your shell functions already preimported in the Jython shell's global namespace.

Comment: @mike: yet another possibility that avoids writing your own shell is to just expose your shell functions as a set of programs that can be used from the OS shell. An example of a program that does this is git (or vagrant or chef's knife or apachectl or ...). Git's design is surprisingly simple but it can do very complex things, and it's an effective demonstration of the unix shell philosophy of a number of small, specialized tools that works together by consuming and producing texts, and using the filesystem to exchange information among the git subcommands.

Comment: I like the git way, but it also has drawbacks, e.g. to properly work on windows they deliver their own git bash shell. Another drawback is that I have to wrap my program around the shell (the same problem with the pyhton approach). But in my opinion the domain model should be agnostic of things like that, the shell has to be wrapped around the application - not the other way round.

Comment: @mike: the reason git needs a bash shell is simply because most of git's commands are (or were) written in bash. The shell you use to interact with git doesn't actually have to be bash (though Windows cmd is so horrible that for your own sanity you shouldn't want to use it). It's possible, at least on theory, to rewrite git so it doesn't use bash at all and your git shell experience wouldn't change. Mercurial is probably a clearer example in this respect, most of mercurial is written in Python, but you can use whatever OS shell you like to use it, but you still need python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74356/discussion-between-mike-and-lie-ryan).